# Ubuntu won't let me boot back into Windows after installing on Surface Pro

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, surface

I installed Ubuntu on my Surface Pro, on a completely separate partition from the main Windows 8 partition. I took the same steps I normally do to dual boot on other machines, but now when I start the machine, instead of giving me options to use either OS, it jumps right into Ubuntu. **How can I boot back into Windows 8?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it...
I restarted and spammed `esc` until Grub2 showed up. At the bottom of the list is "Secue Boot". I selected that and it brought me into the UEFI, where I made it only allow secure OSs. It restarted, said the default OS (Ubuntu) was not secure, and booted into Windows.

Comment: couldn't you choose Windows in the GRUB menu?

Comment: @Zanna Thinking back three and a half years... I don't think so? If I remember correctly, only Ubuntu was in GRUB.